# Django / JS How to make the enter key act like Tab in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I would like to do the same thing than this :

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).next('input').focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

But in a Django form rendered in a template with `{{form}}` to change the enter key behavior in my form and focus the next element each time it's pressed (to act like Tab).

What should I replace the `input` by ?